# Azure not showing custom error page, how do I fix?

Tags: azure

I have an Application Gateway in Azure, in there I have set a custom 503 error webpage at a different url. However when I stop the associated website in Azure and go to the url I still get the generic 503 error webpage. How do I fix this so Azure actually uses the custom page for 503 errors that I set?

I followed the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error

Answer (score 0):

According to [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error)

> The custom error pages are displayed for response codes generated by Application Gateway. If an error originates from the backend server, it is passed along unmodified to the client.

So, when you stop associated website ensure that you need to stop entire server. Suppose if your using virtual machine or app service you should stop the virtual machine and the website.

Application Gateway checks if the back end is available. Service could be anything in your back end, but as long as backend is reachable, even if the service is not working it will give the generic error. therefore, you must stop the virtual machine or app service according to your Servies.

### Update

If your backend pool is vm or app service, check the vm in my case *vm248*

[image]

In virtual machine check the network interface vm248 and stop the vm and same as app service like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I find the corresponding virtual machine or app service?

Comment: The web application is what I am stopping. I'm not sure how to find what else I need to stop.

Comment: Check the updated answer